# How to hide the keyboard toolbar (InputAccessoryView) in WebView in React native? (iOS)

Tags: react-native, keyboard, react-native-ios, inputaccessoryview, react-native-webview

I use WebView in react native and when clicking input and the keyboard open i get with the keyboard toolbar (InputAccessoryView)
how i can hide this line? or control on this part, like change "done" text?

[image: webview keyboard open]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just referred the issues in react-native-webview and found an ios only props called `hideKeyboardAccessoryView` which may resolve this issue. following links are the way i find-out it and the source code reference . this feature available version 2.3.0 or greater

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/38

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/pull/67

[image]

Comment: I try to do this with the old `WebView` (that included in react-native) 
but your answer is good too, so thank you!

Comment: After frustrations for so long and figuring it out I came here to post the answer, am glad you had already found it